# Generate random graph under centrality constraints

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, network

Is it possible to generate a random graph under centrality constraints? I am currently working on a project involving characterization of biological properties stemming from different centrality measures in biological network models. To be able to prove the method generic I need to try it on random networks.

I know that there are models to generate [scale-free](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/286/5439/509.short) and [small-world](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v393/n6684/full/393440a0.html) random graphs. But I am also interested in generating random graphs with a given distribution  of betweenness centralities and closeness centralities. Are there any models to perform that? Other constraints are of interest as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of software for generating random graphs:

- In python with [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/)
- https://github.com/snap-stanford
- [boost c++ library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/erdos_renyi_generator.html)

P.S. I was also interested in generating graphs having nodes with a specific score, but with a different centrality algorithm. Did you came up with something with betweenness?